# Unable to run karma-cli in windows 8

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following node/npm installed on my windows 8 64 bit PC.

```
node --version
v6.3.0

npm --version
3.10.3
```

I was trying to install karma and karma-cli as described [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/installation.html)

I've installed karma-cli with `npm install -g karma-cli` I got `-- karma-cli@1.0.1`.

But when I try `karma` in the command prompt, I get the following message

`Cannot find local Karma!
  Please install karma by 'npm install karma --save-dev'.`

Please let me know how to get karma accessible from command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that when you run `karma` that your working directory is that of your project - at the same level as the "node_modules" directory.

For example, if you have your project containing your "node_modules" directory at 'C:\projects\my_project', you need to navigate to that directory with the command line (or terminal for non-Windows machines) and run karma from there, like so:

```
cd C:\projects\my_project
karma start
```

If you are in the right directory, you should not get that error.

Comment: But I have it installed it globally. Do I need it in module level?

Comment: The way I have always done it is to install Karma at the project level (`npm install karma --save-dev`) and the CLI globally (`npm install -g karma-cli`).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot James

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer.  Thank you and good luck with your work.